# Is it possible to detect pinch zoom start and end gestures in Eclair (2.1)?

Tags: android, events, multi-touch

My app supports Eclair 2.1, API level 7.  I have a need to detect pinch-zoom gestures, both when they start and when they end.  Is this possible without using ScaleGestureListener (only available from 2.2, API level 8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. It would appear that  [SimpleGestureDectector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) is only available in API level 8+.

Comment: Well, I was hoping there might be some workaround, but I think I've found a way to avoid the requirement to do pinch-zoom.   Darn those old phones :)